# Use Sonata Field Type on normal Form Class

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, sonata, form-fields

I'm trying to insert custom sonata form field type on the front page, not in SonataAdmin, something like this:

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($content)
            ->add('titleEs', 'text', array('required' => true, 'label' => 'label.title.spanish', 'attr' => array('class' => 'col-xs-12 form-control input-lg')))
            ->add('contentEs', 'ckeditor', array('required' => true,'label' => 'label.content.spanish', 'attr' => array('class' => 'col-xs-12')))
            ->add('titleEn', 'text', array('required' => true,'label' => 'label.title.english', 'attr' => array('class' => 'col-xs-12 form-control input-lg')))
            ->add('contentEn', 'ckeditor', array('required' => true, 'label' => 'label.content.english', 'attr' => array('class' => 'col-xs-12')))
            ->add('header', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => true,'label' => 'label.content.headerImage'), array('link_parameters' => array('context' => 'content/front', 'size' => 'big')))
            //->add('coverImage', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('required' => true,'label' => 'label.content.coverImage'), array('link_parameters' => array('context' => 'content/front', 'size' => 'small')))
            //->add('sliderImage', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('required' => false,'label' => 'label.content.sliderImage'), array('link_parameters' => array('context' => 'content/slider', 'size' => 'normal')))
            ->getForm();
```

But when I execute that, it throws an error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\ChoiceList\ModelChoiceList::__construct() must implement interface Sonata\AdminBundle\Model\ModelManagerInterface, null given
```

I can't understand why Symfony throws that error, if the Sonata Form Field Types are services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @gabtzi's answer I poked around in the source code of Sonata Admin and came up with a very similar solution. Assuming that we have two entities `Movie` and `Genre` with a many-to-many relation between them (`Movie` is the owning side), the solution in Symfony 4 and Sonata Admin 3.x would look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Movie;
use App\Entity\Genre;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelType;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MovieType extends AbstractType
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // add fields
            ->add('genres', ModelType::class, [
                'multiple' => true,
                'class' => Genre::class,
                'property' => 'name',  // assuming Genre has property name
                'model_manager' => $this->container->get('sonata.admin.manager.orm'),
                'by_reference' => false
            ])
            // add more fields
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Movie::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

This is a very basic example, but should give an idea how to proceed further. Important things are:

- you don't have to register the form type as a service if you use autowiring. Check that `autowire` is set to `true` in your `config/services.yaml`. Read the official [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) for more detailed information;
- pass `ContainerInterface` to the constructor to get the container;
- you don't use `sonata_type_model` anymore. You have to use `ModelType::class`. Pay attention to the use statements;
- you can set `mutiple` to `true` for a M2M relation, otherwise it defaults to `false`;
- you have to pass the entity class to `class` - in this case `Movie::class`;
- you can specify `property` to use certain property of `Genre`. You don't have to declare this if you have defined `__toString` method in the entity class. Then the return value of this method will be used;
- the most important thing: now that you have the container, get the service `sonata.admin.manager.orm` and pass it to `model_manager`. Without this everything falls in water.

I haven't however managed to display the button <kbd>+ Add new</kbd>. It's worth mentioning that admin class for the related property must exist and be accessible (proper permissions set) - in this case `GenreAdmin` would be required, otherwise the button couldn't even theoretically work.

Answer (score 2):

I just bumped into the same issue as you, but since it's the first hit I came across in Google, I'm just posting what I did to work around the issue.
I'm assuming you were dynamically creating the form in a controller. If not you would need to declare your class as a service and inject the `sonata.admin.manager.orm` service to it.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('<name_of_field>', 'sonata_type_model', array(
        'multiple' => true,
        'class' => <className>::class,
        'property' => '<propertyName>',
        'model_manager' => $this->get('sonata.admin.manager.orm')
    ))
;
```

After that it rendered correctly for me as it would in admin context.

Comment: Do you rather think `$this->container->get` instead of `$this->get`? The assumption is that *ContainerInterface* `$this->container` is created in the constructor.

Comment: Since it's been  about 2 years since I posted this answer I can't really remember why i didn't have `$this->container->get`  but you're probably right so I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Yes, it's and old answer, but very valuable. I just wrote my version with some expanded explanations. The credits go to you for giving the hint what to use for `model_manager`.

Comment: I just had an epiphany seeing your code. This worked correctly for me because as I mentioned I was using it in a controller.  The controller back then on my version of symfony could use `$this->get('service')` to retrieve a service directly by it's alias. So this use case was pretty valid. Reading upon your answer I can see it's in a FormType class. Indeed there you could inject the container on the Type and then use `$this->container->get('service')`  but if I recall correctly symfony discourages this because it creates tight coupling. They always suggest to inject only the needed services

Comment: Yes, my answer is how to use it in a FormType class. That is the title of the question. This solution is the best I could come up for now. On the other side creating the form within the controller is not DRY. If you need it somewhere else you have to repeat the code, as it isn't reusable.

Comment: Exactly :) This was a use case where this form would be used only on this single controller and nowhere else in the system. It's nice that we have two solid use cases in these answers because I remember this issue gave me quite a headache. Your explanations help a lot.

Answer (score -2):

sonata_type_model need to know  what kind of entity is related to your field.
If you define this in admin class, sonata use own internal method to check the relation.
So if you define it outside admin it is put null instead entity

Comment: Okay, then how i can specify the class?