# How to configure a Sonata Field Type outside of the Sonata Admin in a Symfony2 Form Class?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

### Use case:

After **using sonata_type_model_list outside of Sonata Admin***, I want to show the same display as in the admin as the following:

[image: sonata-type-model-list field correct display]

However when I add my field to my method buildForm like this:

```
[...]
->add('position', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
    'model_manager' => $categoryAdmin->getModelManager(),
))
[...]
```

my field looks like that :

[image: sonata-type-model-list field wrong display]

Does someone know **how to configure the field to get this display outside of the Sonata Admin**?

---

* See my previous question/use case with title "How to use sonata_type_model_list outside of Sonata Admin?"

Comment: [phpprogrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4141239/phpprogrammer) have you found a solution to this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786191/use-sonata-field-type-on-normal-form-class) ?

Comment: [Piotr Galas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2482094/piotr-galas) could you show us your [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982110/use-sonata-type-collection-inside-custom-type) with more details code ?

Comment: Same problem for me. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: have you found a solution to this issue ? not yet